# What is the highest-energy event "naturally" happening in the current state of the Universe?

Tags: particle-physics, astronomy, observable-universe

I know the question sounds a bit broad, but I will specify it a bit more. I also don't think there is a right answer necessarily, I am just interested in the scales of different processes happening out there.

So under the requirement of being able to observe such process today, with our current state of technology, what is the highest-energy event we have directly observed. As an example we have the recent detection of the black-hole mergers due to gravitational waves and neutrino detection. Where would this event fall in terms of energy? $\sim$TeV's ?, $\sim$GeV's?

Considering a **naturally appearing** phenomenon *something* out of which we can:

1. Still receive its output and infer the typical energies involved with our current measuring devices
2. This output of energy is released in a burst with a duration comparable to a human-lifespan
3. Happens more than once with comparable energies, meaning on average such phenomenon is a very highly energetic phenomenon.

Along such line of thought, which event/phenomenon or observation would currently hold the record?

Comment: What counts as an "event" in the first place?

Comment: It is very hard to define I admit, but let us take a pragmatic view, anything that we can observe, any phenomena for which we can have direct evidence. Stellar formation, a pulsar, black-hole radiation, you name it...

Comment: Does the Big Bang count? We have direct evidence of it happening (namely, the expansion of the universe).

Comment: sure we have evidence but I tried excluding it by saying current state of the universe.. Also I am really pointing at events that although uncommon may happen more than once, so that we can have some statistic perhaps

Comment: Ok, so they must happen more than once, got it. So now I'm a bit confused about your examples of events. Stellar formation isn't a single event, it happens over a period of millions of years. Likewise, a pulsar is an object, not an event. Black-hole radiation is something that happens constantly, so it's unclear how you are dividing it into events.

Comment: Hehehe yeah perhaps event is not the right word, I am using it interchangeably with "phenomenon". But I think you understand what sort of things I am looking at, do you have a suggestion for a better way to refer to these "things"?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what sort of things you intend to look at, since all of your examples refer to different kinds of energy released over vastly different timescales. Ordinarily I would expect that an "event", in this context, would refer to a release of a lot of energy over a very short timescale from a reasonably compact object, but your examples violate this.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/109105/discussion-between-ohneval-and-probably-someone).

Comment: this question is interesting in the sense that makes you think in upper bounds for probabilities of high energy events resulting in vacuum decay/micro black holes/strangelet matter that would end the solar system/milky way/visible universe

Comment: I commented on the chat, but I'll repeat myself here: 

Don't fall in the trap of "moving discussions into the chat", 99.99999% of the time, interesting discussions are lost forever there. Always ALWAYS refuse moving discussions to the chat. Is a Bottomless pit of drowned information.

If the chat exceeds a certain amount of time of inactivity, the logs are purged forever.
on the other hand, comments on the thread remain and are kept visible

Comment: Not much has happened in the chat, I made an edit and tried narrowing down what I meant by phenomenon

Comment: yes. In many cases however, interesting discussion will be drawn toward the chat, for it to be forever lost. In fact just by the fact of warning of this fact, after many years of being on this site, I just got my daily vote quotas limited

Answer (score 0):

I believe the current record for "most energetic event" is a certain recent *gamma ray burst*, whose official designator I cannot remember. If I do I'll add it in an edit so tyou can search on it and learn more.